# doing a serializing a replace but the data i am expecting is not right

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, lucee

I have this function in a cfc which is doing me is returning me the months in an array

```
<cffunction name="getLocaleMonths">
        <cfargument name="sLanguage" required="true" default="1">
        <cfset arrData = []>
        <cfswitch expression="#sLanguage#">
             <cfcase value="10">
                 <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,'"一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月","七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月"')>
             </cfcase>
             <cfcase value="6">
                <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,'"一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月","七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月"')>
             </cfcase> 
             <cfcase value="13">
                <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,'"siječanj", "veljača", "ožujak", "travanj", "svibanj", "lipanj", "srpanj", "kolovoz", "rujan", "listopad", "studeni", "prosinac"')>
             </cfcase>  
             <cfcase value="1">
                <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,'"January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"')>
             </cfcase> 
</cfswitch> 
        <cfset results = Replace(serializeJSON(arrData),'\"',"",'all')>
        <cfreturn results>
     </cffunction>
```

i am doing a serialize but i want my output to be as:

`'["January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]'`

but it is coming like this

`'["January,Febuary,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December"]'`

how can i fix it, i need some rereplace but my knowledge in regex is still growing

please see my updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the array right. It need to look like this

```
  <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,["January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"], true)>
```

Your other arrays have a similar issue.

Note: You misspelled February

Comment: Set the [`merge`](https://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/arrayappend.html#argument-merge) argument to `true` to merge the array, otherwise, you will get an array in an array

Answer (score 1):

I really think you are mixing things up and confusing Strings, Lists and Arrays. I strongly suspect that you need to get an array as a JSON object. Additionally: making some string replacements with REGEX of a JSON object to make that work is not a good path to go.

As James A Mohler already posted, you are not setting the arrays right. I'm going to explain it in more depth for you.

You have embraced all the values in between two single apostrophes `'` as follows.

```
'"January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"'
```

By embracing them that way you have not created an Array, but just one single string with all months within double quotes and separated by comma. Thus, when using the function `arrayAppend()` you are appending just that single string as one only value to your variable `arrData`. In fact, that single string is a `List` of months. When serializing that list with serializeJSON() you will have that CFML list serialized having the wrong/breaking result. And now you want to have that breaking result fixed somehow with some REGEX replacements.

**This is what I'd do:**

1. As James A Mohler correctly said, you need to replace those embracing apostrophes with brackets `["January","Febu ... "December"]`. By doing this you are creating one Array and not a String.
2. What James may have overlooked is that using arrayAppend() like that will still result in the `arrData` containing just one single value (the value of arrdata). To correctly append each of that values to have your expected result, you need to merge them. You can do that by setting `merge` attribute of the [arrayAppend()](https://cfdocs.org/arrayappend) to `true`.
3. You won't need any escaping of the serialized Json because serialize does any JSON escaping correctly by default.

Here is what I think how your code should be:

```
<cffunction name="getLocaleMonths">
        <cfargument name="sLanguage" required="true" default="1">
        <cfset arrData = []>
        <cfswitch expression="#sLanguage#">
             <cfcase value="10">
                 <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,["一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月","七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月"], true )>
             </cfcase>
             <cfcase value="6">
                <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,["一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月","七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月"], true )>
             </cfcase> 
             <cfcase value="13">
                <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,["siječanj", "veljača", "ožujak", "travanj", "svibanj", "lipanj", "srpanj", "kolovoz", "rujan", "listopad", "studeni", "prosinac"], true )>
             </cfcase>  
             <cfcase value="1">
                <cfset arrayAppend(arrData,["January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"], true )>
            </cfcase> 
</cfswitch> 
       
        <cfreturn serializeJSON(arrData)>
     </cffunction>
```

The result is an Array as JSON
`["January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]`